# Curved Monitors Triple Monitor Setup

Tags: monitors, multiple-monitors

So I am ready to finally make the leap to a triple monitor setup.  Shopping for monitors is a horrible experience these days because there is about 9 million options.

I am thinking about going with either 3 24" or 3 27" Monitors. They must be VESA compliant.

I currently use them for mostly business purposes but I do use Illustrator on a daily basis for basic graphic design

My biggest questions is about curved monitors.  Does anyone have any experience working with a trip curved Monitor setup?

The price is negligible at this point in time on curved vs flat.

Are there any drawbacks to the curved monitor setup in this application?

Any advice or comments would be much appreciated

PS  I am currently looking at the following

Samsung CF390 24"
Samsung CF398 27"
Samsung CF391 32" (Is this just too big?)

My other concern is that all the max resolutions are 1920x1080 on these monitors.  I am also not stuck on samsung.

EDITS:

Thanks for the comments so far.

Graphic design would be considered more casual.

Bezel Gap is not a big deal for me.  In fact I prefer the break between the screens to help separate the applications (That being said I have never used a minimal bezel monitor)

I do not play games or use any graphically intensive applications.  Illustrator would be the most intense of the applications on the GPU (and that is not much)

My budget is open but I am trying to stay around or under 1000$ for the 3 monitors.  (Have to have money for the mount)

I really am not sure I am ready to make the leap to a single or double ultrawide.  I feel like with my current work load that the 3 screens will be a better fit.

Cfinley: I am only about 24" away from the monitors so I am really starting to lean away from the 32" option.

Are there other options in the 24-27" range on curved monitors other than samsung?

Comment: Welcome to Hardware Recs! This question leans on opinions, which isn't a good fit for the format of this site. Instead of seeking for opinions, ask about the things that you know you want. The screen size and VESA complaint are a good start, but think about a budget (either for the price of one or all three), resolution, weight, bezel thickness, and what panel tech you want (IPS vs TN). If you edit your question to include these, I would be more than happy to upvote your question.

Comment: To answer your opinion base questions: I would say go with straight monitors (no expirence with curved, I just think it would be better), 32" can be too big, but it depends on how far away the monitors will be. 1080p is fine for 24", but I would look for something better for the bigger screens. Also, go IPS for a triple monitor setup.

Comment: It appears that you have made two accounts. I have flagged this question letting the mods know, so they can help you merge the accounts.

Comment: I ordered 3 of the Samsung 27" Curved Displays.  I will update with my findings after installation.

Comment: Note: Very difficult to find a 3 x 1 or 1 over 3 monitor stand that has 27" monitor support.  This is a big problem with this setup but nothing a trip to home depot and some ingenuity did not fix.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple questions in there which may warrant more than one post across multiple SE sites. I'll throw in my experience on the curved display part.

I currently use a [Dell U3415W](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16824260239), a 34'' curved 60hz 21:9 3440x1440 monitor. It has the more gentle curve (3800r IIRC) than something like the BenQ 3501 (2000r, lower = more extreme curve = more strict viewing position).

From my experience the curve has much more of a "....wow!" factor than any sort of practical use however this is likely compounded by just how giant my monitor is. I wouldn't say my workflow has improved necessarily any more than it would if I had gotten a flat-screened monitor, but moving from a pair of 27'' 1080p screens (thus eliminating the bezel gap) and adding pixels has absolutely helped. The window management software is very usable and doesn't really get in the way.

I'd be careful about getting a curved display if your design work is anything more than casual as the curve is literally a distortion of the image (albeit minor) and may not reflect the true image with 100% precision.

Having triple monitors means you'll need to consider both the number of video outputs on your machine as well as its ability to push the pixels. If you aren't doing anything intense the second point is pretty much null on any processor/gpu. Once you start running games or high res photo/video projects you need to consider how many pixels are really in front of you (1080p = 2,073,600 pixels. 3x 1080p = 6,220,800, 4k = 8,294,400) and at what refresh rate (60hz, 144hz). Horsepower on GPUs/APUs starts to dwindle quickly when you're throwing high resolutions at high framerates.